# How to align texts to each Textinput - React Native

Tags: react-native, text, textinput, text-alignment

I want those texts in the left to be aligned to my Textinputs on the right.
I am fetching textinputs and texts from api so they are dynamic. I need to display each text on the left side of the texinput.
Here is my code:

```
 textfieldsObject = () => {
    const obje = this.props.navigation.state.params.item;
    var keyvalue_to_json = JSON.parse(obje.keyValues);
    var textinputName = [];
    var foundTextFields = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < keyvalue_to_json.inputFields.length; i++) {
        if (keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].type === 'textfield') {
            foundTextFields.push(<TextInput placeholder={keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].placeholderText} style={styles.inputFields}
                onEndEditing={(e) => {
                    keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].inputValues = e.nativeEvent.text;
                    this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i] = keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i];
                }}
            ></TextInput>) &&
                textinputName.push(<Text style={{ textAlign: 'left', flex: 2 }}>{keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].title}</Text>)
        }
    }
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                {textinputName}
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                {foundTextFields}
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are You want to show Full name to center with Enter your full name???

Comment: Please add the original code that produced this output.

Comment: @VishalDhanotiya yes I want to do exactly that. How can I do it?

Comment: @BMX plese check i have added my answer it will help to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

I have write small piece of code . You can try this code. It may solve your problem. Please also [check this code](https://snack.expo.io/@vishalcodiant/anxious-candy) into snack and directly run to scan QR using Expo app. Please c[image: heck this UI preview]

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { TextInput, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignContent: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', flex: 1, padding: 15 }}>
            {'Full name'}
          </Text>
          <TextInput
           placeholder='Enter Your Full Name'
          placeholderTextColor='#303030'
            style={{
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#000',
              flex: 1,
              padding: 15,
            }}/>

        </View>
         <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignContent: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', flex: 1, padding: 15 }}>
            {'CRP Number'}
          </Text>
          <TextInput
          placeholder='Enter Your CRP Number'
          placeholderTextColor='#303030'
            style={{
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#000',
              flex: 1,
              padding: 15,
            }}/>

        </View>
         <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignContent: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', flex: 1, padding: 15 }}>
            {'Company Name'}
          </Text>
          <TextInput
             placeholder='Enter Your Company Name'
          placeholderTextColor='#303030'
            style={{
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#000',
              flex: 1,
              padding: 15,
            }}/>

        </View>
         <View
          style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignSelf: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            alignContent: 'center',
            flexDirection: 'row',
          }}>
          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', flex: 1, padding: 15 }}>
            {'Company CVR '}
          </Text>
          <TextInput
          placeholder='Enter Your company CVR'
          placeholderTextColor='#303030'
            style={{
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor: '#000',
              flex: 1,
              padding: 15,
            }}>
            {'Enter Your company CVR'}
          </TextInput>
        </View>

        <Text style={{ color:'#fff',borderRadius:50, width:300, height:50, textAlign:'center', padding:15, marginTop:70,backgroundColor:'#00b5ec'}}>{"Click to sign in"}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginRight:1
  },
});
```

**Updated Answer Please Check**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { FlatList, TextInput, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      jsonData: [
        { id: 1, textName: 'Hello', textInputName: 'Full Name' },
        {
          id: 2,
          textName: 'Hello',
          textInputName: 'Last Name',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          textName: 'Hello',
          textInputName: 'Date of Birth',
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          textName: 'Hello',
          textInputName: 'Address',
        },
        { id: 1, textName: 'Hello', textInputName: 'Full Name' },
        {
          id: 2,
          textName: 'Hello',
          textInputName: 'Last Name',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          textName: 'Hello',
          textInputName: 'Date of Birth',
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          textName: 'Hello',
          textInputName: 'Address',
        },
        { id: 1, textName: 'Hello', textInputName: 'Full Name' },
        {
          id: 2,
          textName: 'Hello',
          textInputName: 'Last Name',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          textName: 'Hello',
          textInputName: 'Date of Birth',
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          textName: 'Hello',
          textInputName: 'Address',
        },
      ],
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          style={{ width: '100%', flex: 1 }}
          data={this.state.jsonData}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View
              style={{
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignSelf: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                alignContent: 'center',
                flexDirection: 'row',
              }}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', flex: 1, padding: 15 }}>
                {item.textName}
              </Text>
              <TextInput
                placeholder={item.textInputName}
                placeholderTextColor="#303030"
                style={{
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  borderColor: '#000',
                  flex: 1,
                  padding: 15,
                }}
              />
            </View>
          )}
        />

        <Text
          style={{
            color: '#fff',
            borderRadius: 50,
            width: 300,
            height: 50,
            textAlign: 'center',
            padding: 15,
            marginTop: 10,
            backgroundColor: '#00b5ec',
            marginBottom: 20,
          }}>
          {'Click to sign in'}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,

    marginTop: 10,
    marginRight: 1,
  },
});
```

I have also added updated snack expo please check

https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/anxious-candy

Comment: I am using dynamic textinputs and texts as you can see.

Comment: What is mean of dynamic textinput or text ?? Value of text is dynamic or multiple text input create dynamically??

Comment: They are fetched from an api, rendered and displayed as I have posted the code. Basically I am displaying there two arrays, one textinputs and the other with texts

Comment: just use my code, do not change it because it doesnt make sense. And dont use component <Textinput> or <Text> because I am calling an array there so I cant use these components besides <View>

Comment: Sorry, @BMX I can't help you anymore because of your code logically incorrect. There is no need to push view into an array. Its increase rendering time

Comment: Vishal, I am not pushing View into an array. Please go through my code carefully, what are you saying is not related to my code. Make sure you understand what the code does before saying is 'logically incorrect'.

Comment: As you can see I am not pushing View into an array (that doesnt make sense), I am pushing textfields fetched from API in to an array, and then I am displaying that array in View.

Comment: Then what is meaning of this var textinputName = []; var foundTextFields = [] foundTextFields.push(<TextInput placeholder={keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].placeholderText} style={styles.inputFields} }></TextInput>) && textinputName.push(<Text style={ textAlign: 'left', flex: 2 }}></Text>) }. You push text input in array there is need to make array of text input bcoz react native already provide flatlist for rendering dynamic view. If you push view or textinput into array then render into view i will take more time to reder view

Comment: Pushing view or textinput into array both are same thing it slow down your app. I only suggest if are make dynamic view use scrollview with map or flatlist

Comment: You cant display dynamic textinputs and texts directly without pushing them first to an array. I am really curious to see how would you do it!

Comment: As per you code you get **type** tag from you api response. And then you push textinput and text according to type tag.   Right!!!!

Comment: I have already added my updated answer. You receive json response for api then put into array and pass that api response in flatlist data props then according to response flat list make dynamic view according to you json length. In render Item you can make view which do you want to make dynamically multiple time.

Comment: You can check this code on snack.          https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/anxious-candy.           You can change json object count if you json lenghth is 1 single row is create then you increase ot to 4 rowbof view is also increasing

Comment: The textFields I am fetching from API are JSON objects and thats why I am doing that. And each object is one textInput. I tried your option but it doesnt display anything. Check your snack.expo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191036/discussion-between-bmx-and-vishal-dhanotiya).

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to create Views with the same size. Once this is done, put inside the Text compnent with tha margin you want or the view style properties to align the text.

Either with View Style properties or Text, if the View containing the 2 texts are the same size the texts components wioll be aligned to each other.

Comment: Can you show an example, I am not sure if  i got it!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the code below, what I do is wrapping your text components with a
view, and both views wrapping the text has the exact same size.
Once this is done, the Text components inside these views has width and height 100%, so it will be the same size as the view. This way you will have 2 components aligned in your main View with flex-direction = row, and the text will be aligned.
Copy the code below and set up the size of the views inside the style props of both views where I commented the code

```
 <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    justifyContent: 'space-between'
                }}
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        //Here You set up with and height
                    }}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            height: '100%',
                            width: '100%',
                            textAlign: 'center'
                        }}
                    >
                        {textinputName}
                    </Text>
                </View>

                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        //And here you set up the same with and height than the first view
                    }}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            height: '100%',
                            width: '100%',
                            textAlign: 'center'
                        }}
                    >
                        {foundTextFields}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
```

Comment: but I need textinputs to remain the same width all the time, and have space between each other when text on the left is too long.